# In ASP.NET MVC3, how should one render multiple PartialViews backed by multiple Models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, models

In MVC3 Razor, how do you create a page with multiple forms, so that each form is a partial view rendered with its own model?

We have been trying various forms of calling Html.RenderPartial(), passing in the partialview name as well as an instance of our models that we're accessing through the ViewBag, but every method we've tried seems to have serious issues, and so we must have a fundamental misunderstanding of how this is supposed to operate in an ideal world.

We have found some SO responses on similar topics ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419889/asp-net-mvc2-how-to-render-a-view-if-has-multiple-different-models)) recommending a "super model" that contains references to each of the sub models our partial views might need to use, but we cannot find an example of how you would actually use those submodels' data, e.g. when trying to write EditorTemplates.

**Edit:** Let me clarify my question a bit. We ARE able to render a partialview or even an action (using RenderAction as Mark S. recommended). However, our primary trouble is that when those forms submit back to, e.g. save the state of the Model in that partialview area, the Controller doesn't seem to know what model we're referencing. How should we be calling into the Controller?

We've tried a few different ways of rendering these partial views. Our first try was like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveAccountInfo", null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "section1-form" }))
{
    @Html.EditorForModel("AccountInfo", (OurModels.AccountInfo) ViewBag.account_info)
}
```

The ViewBag.account_info contains the Model data for this one partial view.

We've also tried:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("FormAccountInfo", (OurModels.AccountInfo) ViewBag.account_info);}
```

And now:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("FormAccountInfo", "Main", new { account_info = (OurModels.AccountInfo) ViewBag.account_info }); }
```

But no matter which method we use for rendering this one form on the page, when that form gets submitted for processing, we can't seem to access any of the submitted data via the Model? I feel like we're doing something really dumb, but we're new to MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get bogged down in abstractions, from the time you render the page to the time the controller method is called you're working in HTML and HTTP only.

If you want to post back to a different method there's numerous ways to do so. You can have multiple HTML forms on your page, or you can use something like jQuery to perform a post. Which controller action picks up your post and what data is sent back is determined by the form on the HTML page and its contents. The MVC handlers will pick up the request, and attempt to bind the request URL and contents to one of the available actions that match it.

To "post back a model" you need to send the data back to a suitable action in such a way that the model-binder can read it. This could be JSON data (if you're using MVC 3) or a form with name-value pairs. The controller though knows nothing about the page that is requesting the data, or how it was created. It doesn't even know whether the request is being made by a page.

You can try this for yourself by making a normal HTML page with a form on it that is set up to post to the URL of one of your MVC controllers. So long as the names of the form fields match the names of the properties on the argument of your controller action, MVC will bind it and call the action.

If you have complex views, you may well find that jQuery post is the way to go, with some client-side methods that gather data from the page and create JSON objects to send back. Using that method gives you very precise control over what data is sent back, whereas with forms you have limitations (such as overlapping data etc).

Edit - response to comment

Here's an example that is using raw HTML only to show a very simple case:

```
Public Class HomeController

    'Other action methods...

    <HttpPost()>
    Function SayHello(myName As String) As ActionResult
        Return Content("Hello " & myName)
    End Function

End Class
```

And HTML form (I plonked this on the Index view but it could go absolutely anywhere)

```
<form action="/Home/SayHello" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="myName" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I've set the name on the `<input>` to match the parameter name, which gives MVC a helping hand. While there is only 1 value being posted back though, I could name it something else. However if I did this:

```
<form action="/Home/SayHello" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="aName" />
    <input type="text" name="anotherName" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

...then the model binder wouldn't know which value it should use, and you'd get values not being set properly.

Change to this however:

```
<form action="/Home/SayHello" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="myName" />
    <input type="text" name="anotherName" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

... and the model binder is now able to use the name to correctly identify which value to use and which to ignore.

In the case of strongly typed actions:

```
Public Class HomeController

    <HttpPost()>
    Function SayHello(person As SimplePerson) As ActionResult
        Return Content("Hello " & person.FirstName)
    End Function

End Class

Public Class SimplePerson
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property Surname As String
End Class
```

You need to have form names that correspond with property names. My aName/anotherName form would send back the right shape, but the model binder wouldn't set any properties because it doesn't know what is what. This however would work:

```
<form action="/Home/SayHello" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" />
    <input type="text" name="Surname" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is shedding some light into how MVC processes things which weren't clear to me before. It seems now that our problem may lie elsewhere, then, since we are seeing the action called, it's just that the Model object being passed into the routine has empty/default values, and ModelState.IsValid is false when it shouldn't be. Do the MVC handlers create an instance of the model, and then set each property based on the HTTP post parameters? Any recommendations for debugging where this aspect is failing?

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much it. There's naming conventions which help the model binder along, which is where the HTML helpers come in handy as they look after that kind of thing. For debugging, you can use something like Fiddler or the browser's development tools to inspect the requests you are making, or inspect the Request from within your controller.

Comment: Thanks Richard for your help. We are still running into an issue where we are posting back, we are sending all of the correctly named form values that match up to our Model properties, and the binder is sending us into the proper method with an instance of our Model being passed in -- but the property values are all at the default. I've tried adding breakpoints on the various setters, but they are not being hit. It's like the binder is creating the instance, but not setting the property names from the HTML form values for some reason. I will mark your response up as soon as I have street cred.

Comment: Something else that could potentially help is that you can download the full source code for ASP.Net MVC from CodePlex - http://aspnet.codeplex.com/ - and then instead of referencing the DLL that ships, reference the source code version. That would allow you to inspect code, set breakpoints inside the framework, and see exactly what's going where. I think the default model binder uses reflection to set property values - so you probably wouldn't see your setters being called? You may need to put in a layer of ViewModels with simple properties, and then create domain objects from those.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Html.RenderAction()` method.  It provides a bunch of functionality that allows you to you to render and action and have it call get it own information from your data store.  Here is a link to the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction.aspx.

Comment: OK, thanks. We saw this as an alternative to RenderPartial, but were hoping there was something more intuitive that we were just missing. I'm still trying to identify a good resource that illustrates how to do something similar using RenderAction (or RenderPartial, or similar). Who oh why isn't it as simple as rendering PartialViews, where each PartialView specifies its @model? :-)