# MVC 3 Multiple Forms Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

Having read [In ASP.NET MVC3, how should one render multiple PartialViews backed by multiple Models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783443/in-asp-net-mvc3-how-should-one-render-multiple-partialviews-backed-by-multiple), and some others, I still don't know the best way to go about validating multiple partial-view--forms--models on a page.

I don't doubt that whatever's compelling me to think of them as triples right now is the problem. All I ask is that the "why's" be comments and the answers be answers.

I have a view, "Editor", that does multiple render-actions that prefill some forms:

```
@{
Html.RenderAction("EditName", new { name = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["ID"]});
}
@{
//returns EditColor partial view prefilled with this widget's color's properties
Html.RenderAction("EditColor", new { name = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["ID"]}); 
}
```

So I have an EditColorFormModel that has something like (since I don't want extravagant color names)...

```
[StringLength(8)]
public String Name
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

And I have a POST action to accept the EditColorForm submit with something like...

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return View("Editor", EditColorFormModel);
}
```

But if so, I get stack overflow. I guess that's because this model hits that RenderAction to start the loop. I tried `RedirectToAction("Editor", EditColorFormModel)`, but the validation messages don't get to the summary helper under EditColor partial view, which I'm assuming is because the model does not hit the RenderAction after all. So does it, or doesn't it, and what should I do?

---

My own answer is that I didn't ask the right question, and that I need a complete isolated example of the problem. I left the model out because there's no logic there, it's got some properties with validation attributes applied.

Controller:

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult ColorEditor(Int32 WidgetId)
    {
        return PartialView(new Models.WidgetColorModel() { 
            Id = WidgetId
            //prefill whatever else on form 
        });
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult DimensionEditor(Int32 WidgetId) 
    {
        //same for dim
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ColorEditor(Models.WidgetColorModel m)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something not Kosher-colored in Denmark");
            return View("Editor", m);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DimensionEditor(Models.WidgetDimensionModel m)
    {
        //same for dim
    }
```

View:

```
<body>
    <div>
        @{
            Html.RenderAction("ColorEditor", new { WidgetId = Context.Request.Params["WidgetId"]});
            Html.RenderAction("DimensionEditor", new { WidgetId = Context.Request.Params["WidgetId"]});
        }
    </div>
</body>
```

Partial Views (DimensionEditor is structured exactly the same):

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.WidgetColorModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("ColorEditor","Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <span>Specialized color editor for Widget @Model.Id</span>
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type=submit name= "ColSubmit" value="Sumbit" />
}
```

1. Top-level view does RenderAction
2. ChildAction controller executes
3. Top-level view does RenderAction for the second editor
4. ChildAction controller executes
5. I fill in a bad value on one of the forms and submit
6. HttpPost action method picks it up, adds error message, and tries to render the top-level view with the same model
7. Top-Level view does RenderAction
8. HttpPost action method picks it up again (in the words of Rick Perry, "...")

And the result is a stack overflow exception because the `View("Editor")` reenters the `Editor(Model)` action method with `RenderAction` which warns about merging the RouteValues.

My question, of course, is what to change/insert, based on what, and where (in the controller, stupid) to prevent the overflow.

Comment: You keep referring to a model 'hitting' a RenderAction. What do you mean by that? models should not be calling into anything like an action method...

Comment: how does you action result looks like

Comment: @AndrewBarber -- I can't think of what would create an overflow if the RenderAction in my top level view isn't getting handled by the POST action method, after that same method tries to redirect to the top level view after getting the form data / binding to the model

Comment: `RenderAction` probably does not pay any attention whatsoever to `HttpGet` `HttpPost` attributes on controller actions. It's probably just going to match what it can match based on the method signature. If that's the only method that's re-entrant, then it's almost certainly that's your problem.